# How to update setListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am using setListAdapter for displaying the users online..

Here's my code:

```
Vector<String> myvector= Receiver.user;
int i =0;
String[] strings =new String[myvector.size()];
  for(String str : myvector) {
strings[i] = str;
  i++;
  }
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Display.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings));
```

The vector gets updated every time a new user comes online.But the display is not changing.
How to update it??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

use the `notifyDataSetChanged()` of ArrayAdapter

[Check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Answer (score -2):

Create your code as a method

for example 
make it as

```
public void yourMethod()
{
Vector<String> myvector= Receiver.user;
int i =0;
String[] strings =new String[myvector.size()];
  for(String str : myvector) {
strings[i] = str;
  i++;
  }
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Display.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings));
}
```

call this Method.
When a user is created newly

so that it works

Comment: No need to set adapter each time he can use `notifyDataSetChanged()` see @sankar answer